# Apache Cordova security vulnerability

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-security

I've recently uploaded an android app to Google Play and I've got the well known security vulnerability warning [Apache Cordova security vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200127/how-to-check-cordova-android-version-of-a-cordova-phonegap-project). I'm a bit confused because I'm using Cordova CLI 6.0.0 and Cordova Android 5.1.1. What I'm doing wrong?

Project info:

```
>cordova platform ls
Installed platforms: android 5.1.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, webos, windows, windows8, wp8

>cordova --version
6.0.0

>cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2-dev "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1-dev "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.2-dev "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1-dev "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.1-dev "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.3-dev "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1-dev "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.1-dev "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2-dev "Whitelist"
```

I've tried to add/remove next lines in config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```

I've also tried adding and removing next line in index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

This is the email I received from Google Play Team:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We rejected XXXXXX, package ID XXXXXXX, for
>   violating our Malicious Behavior policy. If you submitted an update,
>   the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users.
>
> Below is the list of vulnerabilities and the corresponding APK
>   versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade
>   your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of
>   the upgraded APK.
>
> Vulnerability APK Version(s) Apache Cordova The vulnerabilities were
>   fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1.
>
> You can find more information and next steps in this [Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6325474).

Comment: search your project for old cordova.js files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jcesarmobile said, there are several cordova.js files in the cordova project. I had to update not only the main cordova.js file in www folder but I had to manually update this file in other folders (such as /platform/android/assets/www); then I was able to upload a new version without Security Warnings in Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot - and one not explicitly mentioned by Google although they are looking for XSS exposures - but have you perhaps added an 'unsafe-inline' to the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src` in your `index.html` to allow inline Jscript to be included?

Comment: No. I haven't used any security policy in my index.html